# If a window is fullscreen, how do I keep it open?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I like to play a lot of games, all by Valve (So they have the valve options interface). They're all launched through steam.

I have two monitors. When I click on the monitor that does't have the game on it, the game gets minimized. However, I know it's still running because I can still hear sounds playing (and it's the actual sounds I'd hear if it weren't minimized)

How do I keep it up even if I click another monitor? My mouse can LEAVE the monitor the game's on fine but clicking will minimize it.

**Before anyone says this is off-topic because it's about games: This isn't about games. It could be about any application that goes fullscreen. My case just happens to be about a game.**

Comment: Just to be pedantic, this is actually about games (specifically tied to Valve/Steam), since most full screen apps will stay maximized . . . but I still think it's a valid question.

Comment: Most full screen apps, not just games. But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have the program/game in fullscreen mode and in fullscreen mode this isn't possible. (believe it's related to how graphic drivers dedicates more power to a single fullscreen program)

A popular option is instead to use fullscreen windowed mode which is essentially just window mode thats been maximized with it's borders remove. (this requires more power though since the graphics card need to handle your entire desktop now instead of dedicating more or less all it's focus on a single program/screen).

If the game doesn't support fullscreen window mode you can run the game in window mode, maximize it and find one of many programs (you should google it ;)) to remove the borders.

Comment: I could do that (it's built into the game) however it looks so much worse.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. It seems windows *wants* to minimise the full screen app/game but doesn't *need* to. I can use voice attack to switch the focus from a full screen game to a browser BUT if I make any change to any window (resize/minimise/move) the game gets minimised. If I don't do any changes to any window I can use the browser while the game is up and running on the other monitor (I can switch to other apps clicking them but not with alt-tab). To do this I created a voice attack command that does:
`Display window '*Mozilla Firefox' as [Normal]`

HTH

Comment: I just realised this is REALLY old and tagged windows 8. I tested my solution on windows 10.